# flashdevelop error while loading initial content

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air, flashdevelop

I have been struggling with this stupid error from couple of hours. Have tried everything but it still persists. I'm unable to run any Flash Mobile AS3 project in FlashDevelop.

This is what it says in Output panel:

```
Debugger startup error. For troubleshooting see: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=F.A.Q
Error details: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Dll.JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(JavaVMInitArgs* args)
   at net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Init()
   at net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.CreateJavaVM(JavaVM& jvm, JNIEnv& env, Boolean attachIfExists, String[] options)
   at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.CreateJVM()
   at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.CreateJVM(BridgeSetup setup)
   at FlashDebugger.DebuggerManager.Start(Boolean alwaysStart)
[Capturing traces with FDB]
```

and this is what it shows in the console/command prompt:

```
error while loading initial content
```

Please if anyone had seen this error and solved it successfully, I would really appreciate any help. **Screenshot attached below.**

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you pass an argument to increase memory? like `-jvmopt="-Xmx1024M"` I think the default amount is like `-jvmopt="-Xmx256M"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using wrong Java SDK version 64 bit rather than 32 bit which FlashDevelop requires

Comment: interesting... Also when using Crossbridge I had 32-bit Java (though it recommends 64-bit Java ) and to compile anything I had to use `-jvmopt="-Xmx1024M"` to increase memory allocation in the command line. Since it was C++ not Java the full thing looked like `gcc -jvmopt="-Xmx256M" hello.c -o hello.exe` so I wonder if the asker has to do similar with FlashDevelop? I don't use it so just a thought process...